# Non-Static method requires a target?

Tags: linq

I have never seen this error before and its very confusing, I am essentially trying to do something where I say find me all locations (will only return one) that match the location name passed in and the type:

```
string name = columns[40];
Location type = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == type.type).FirstOrDefault();
```

There's probably a better way to do what I want in one fell swoop, but essentially I get the name from a column (this comes from a csv file), and then say, get me that locations information. After this I say ok now that I have all that jazz, go get me a location with this name and its type.

But I get the error:

Non-Static method requires a target

The top level method all this code runs in is:

```
static void Main(string[] args){}
```

Essentially its just a console app. So whats going on?

- **db** is the context class, this should be obvious.
- **columns** is me pulling the data from the csv file, in this case columns[40] would be something like "New York"

**Full Error message from the stack trace:** {"Non-static method requires a target."}

**Note:** The question posted as a "possible answer" does not help in this case as the main method I am running this code in is static.

Upon further investigation I found the name and type were null so I did the following fix:

```
if (name != null)
{
    Location type = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
    Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == type.type).FirstOrDefault();
    locationNearbyId = loc.id;

    // More code
}
```

Alas I still get the error at: `Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == type.type).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Where *exactly* is the error? What is `db`? What is `columns`?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? Which non-static method is it talking about? On which line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method requires a target C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577191/non-static-method-requires-a-target-c-sharp)

Comment: Question has been updated, the possible answer, does not help me. please expand more on this. @JonSkeet Please read the full question before answering

Comment: Do either one of `name` or `type.type` in your second expression happen to be null?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError editied: Yes they are both null, this would explain a lot

Comment: That's a compilation error.  What line is it occurring on?

Comment: @antlersoft I belive the question was answered as name and type are null >.> but: `Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == type.type).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Is `db` actually a *class* or a *variable*? It's not at *all* obvious. It's also very odd that you're getting what sounds like a compile-time error but as an exception. Additionally, you haven't said which version of LINQ you're using.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this happen to me today. Come to find out, I was doing this:

```
Player player = db.Players
    .Where(p => p.ClubID == course.Club.ID && p.IsActive == true && p.Phone != null)
    .ToArray()
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Phone.FormatPhoneNumber() == phone);
```

where `course.Club` was being lazy-loaded via EF from my database. At first, I thought my problem was the `FormatPhoneNumber` extension, but then found that removing the `course.Club.ID` fixed the issue:

```
int clubID = course.Club.ID;
Player player = db.Players
    .Where(p => p.ClubID == clubID && p.IsActive == true && p.Phone != null)
    .ToArray()
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Phone.FormatPhoneNumber() == phone);
```

So, avoid using values gleaned from lazy-loaded objects in subsequent LINQ queries - assign them to local variables and then use those variables in your query.

Comment: Awesome explanation! It's a common Linq gotchya that often get's forgotten, as a rule I always evaluate properties of local objects to local variables before I use them in Linq queries because you never know when someone else is going to blindly refactor your code or regenerate your data classes with lazy loading enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that because name and type can be null type has to be set out side the if statement and thus i must check if type and name are null before continueing:

```
name = collumns[40];
type = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name).FirstOrDefault();

if (name != null && type != null)
{
    Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && l.type == type.type).FirstOrDefault();

    //More code....
}
```

Comment: This seems very unlikely to be the cause, as the error message you've given sounds like it's really a compiler error. But then you said you're getting it as an exception. Unfortunately as your question is pretty vague and incomplete, it's hard to help you or say for sure whether this answer is actually relevant or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet The error is very confusing when you don't know what it means. I was getting this error as well when using a variable returned from a linq query (my query pulled back one object). That object turned out to be `null`. Once you know it's a null object, it makes tons of sense. You're calling a non-static method (`type.type`) without a target (the target `type` is null). It's just a really cryptic error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fact that the problem is due to the null "type" object.
I would solve this way:

```
var tType = type?.type;
Location loc = db.Locations.Where(l => l.name == name && (type != null && l.type == tType)).FirstOrDefault();
```