# Handling empty collections in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I fill up a List in Entity Framework;

```
    List<StockProperties> props = db.StockProperties
                                    .Where(prop => prop.Stok_ID == stok.ID)
                                    .ToList();
```

The problem here is if my query is null, it returns a

> Non-static method requires a target.

error which is obvious since EF does that with empty sequences.My question is what is the most reasonable way to handle these null queries?I want my list to be empty if my query returns null sequences.

Comment: "If my query is null"? I don't see any nulls here, except perhaps `stok`.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty is a handy method you can use here. You can specify default vaules for each stock. Also, why not just check if List is null or List.Length > 0

Comment: Im not getting this, is an exception thrown or is `props`simply just `null` ? because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code, and if the EF query returns 0 rows you should get an empty list. If its an exception, could you show us the stacktrace?

Comment: The code sample should return an empty `List<StockProperties>` (assuming no matches). If it's not, you'll need to provide more detail. Is the exception perhaps occurring later when you try to use the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
List<StockProperties> props = db.StockProperties
                                .Where(prop => false)
```

Is returning a `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<StockProperties>` with 0 reccords it will never be `null`.

Your problem may be with `prop => prop.Stok_ID == stok.ID`

Do stok is declared?

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570960/non-static-method-requires-a-target)

Answer (score -1):

You can supply a fall back option for `null`

```
var props = 
    db.StockProperties.Where(prop => prop.Stok_ID == stok.ID)
    ?? Enumerable.Empty<StockProperties>();
```

or

```
var props = 
    db.StockProperties.Where(prop => prop.Stok_ID == stok.ID).ToList()
    ?? new List<StockProperties>();
```

Comment: `Queryable.Where` (or `Enumerable.Where`) won't *ever* return a `null` value.