# How to check in a linq query for null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying in a linq query to check if one of the fields is null but i get this error whatever i do.

"Non-static method requires a target."

This is my code :

```
var users = from s in db.Users
                        where s.DepartmentId == booking.Item.DepartmentId && s.UserEmail != null
                        select s;
```

is any way to go through this error and be able to actually check if UserEmail is null?

p.s : i am using asp.net mvc entity framework.

Comment: The exception you're getting comes from [trying to invoke a non-static method from a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577191/non-static-method-requires-a-target-c-sharp).  You're going to need to post more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the first 2 letters are uppercase (DBNull.Value).

EDIT:

Try to copy your booking item into a local variable.

```
var departmentId = booking.Item.DepartmentId;
var users = from s in db.Users
where s.DepartmentId == departmentId && s.UserEmail != null
select s;
```

Comment: ok i got the DBNull.Value and now i get this error : Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: hmm yeah in that case, it looks like it was right as it was before (!= null). You can also try and use "!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.UserEmail)". However, it looks like you have some other error related to your static method... (is UserEmail just a string property?)

Comment: i tried that as well and i get the same error : "Non-static method requires a target."
Yes , UserEmail is just a string property.

Comment: And other question.. why if you remove this part? "&& s.UserEmail != null", Will it work then? (Just checking that the issue is coming from here and not somewhere else)

Comment: Try this...
    var departmentId = booking.Item.DepartmentId;var users = from s in db.Users where s.DepartmentId == departmentId && s.UserEmail != null
select s;

Comment: what i got now for booking.item.DepartmentId was : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: LOL nice...  are booking, Item and DepartmentId not null? maybe you will need to also check those cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = from s in db.Users
     where s.DepartmentId == booking.Item.DepartmentId && s.UserEmail != DbNull.Value                                
     select s;
```

You need to compare it to [DbNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: its says DbNull does not exist in current context ? its strange because i am using the system namespace!

Comment: ok i got the DBNull.Value and now i get this error : Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: var users = from s in db.Users
     where s.DepartmentId == booking.Item.DepartmentId && string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.UserEmail) == false                                 
     select s;